# Can I get a parent process ID using "top"?

Tags: command-line

I'm doing some homework that requires me to get the entire column that shows the parent Process ID, can you help me find out the proper command to get this information from?

Answer (score 0):

nvm I used

ps aox ppid,pid,pmem,pcpu,cmd

And it shows every column that I specified after the aox